# Recursividad en Javascript. ¿Por qué esto funciona?

Tags: javascript, funciones, recursión

Estoy practicando en freeCodeCamp y llegué a la parte de recursividad. El ejercicio es el siguiente: Write a recursive function, sum(arr, n), that returns the sum of the first n elements of an array arr.

Gracias al ejemplo de la pagina de un problema similar pude llegar a la siguiente respuesta

```
function sum(arr, n) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if (n==0){
    return 0;
  } else {
    return sum(arr, n-1) + arr[n-1];
  }
}
```

Sin embargo, estoy queriendo apuntar la lógica detras de esta solución y por alguna razón no termino de entender como llega al resultado que espero. Supongamos que la llamo con los siguientes parametros

sum([1,2,3],2)

En primera instancia el código chequea que el valor n no sea 0, en este caso no lo es entonces prosigue.
A continuación devuelve la misma función restandole 1 a n sumandole el numero que se encuentre en la posición n-1 del array. Lo que no entiendo es en que momento lo suma, si no existen dos numeros para sumar. Me es facil ubicar array[n-1] en el calculo pero no logro entender la logica detras de como sum(arr, n-1) se convierte en un numero para poder realizar el calculo.

Espero que se haya entendido la consulta y quedo a disposición si es necesario ampliar mi consulta. Saludos y buenas tardes!

Answer (score 4):

La recursividad funciona de una manera muy interesante!!

Primero que nada se debe definir un caso base, es decir, debe haber una opción que permita en algún momento retornar un valor y no una llamada a función con distintos parámetros. Para tu ejemplo el caso base sería:

```
if(n==0){
    return 0;
}
```

Al comienzo es un poco difícil pensar de modo que tu caso base sea correcto. Pero de forma poco técnica se puede decir que tu función si o sí debe pasar por el caso base en algun momento de la recursión para que se pueda solucionar.

Aquí un ejemplo más gráfico de tu solución:

[image: recursion]

Si te fijas se sigue llamando a la función hasta llegar al caso base, mientras se hace esto las demás funciones quedan en espera. Una vez retornado el valor del caso base, se puede solucionar la función previa.

*Esta explicación no abarca todos los temas de la recursividad, pero espero te sirva como guía.*

Si te interesa seguir aprendiendo sobre estos temas te invito a investigar acerca de recursividad y si deseas aumentar tus conocimientos sobre funciones investiga sobre el paradigma funcional.

Comment: Donosito, la explicación es increible. Muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en poder graficarlo de forma lo mas clarificadora posible. Ahora dejame preguntarte lo siguiente. ¿Cual es el sentido entonces de utilizar recursividad cuando existen los bucles? ¿Cual es la aplicación practica?

Comment: @alejoevilches La recursión no suele ser muy usada en el día a día, debido a que requiere de una mayor demanda de recursos. Pero en algunos casos (cuando el código se vuelve más complejo) se puede considerar a la recursividad como una solución debido a que es más facil de leer he incluso de codificar. Te invito a leer [este algorítmo](https://apuntes.de/golang-estructuras-de-datos-y-algoritmos/funciones-recursivas-las-torres-de-hanoi/#gsc.tab=0). Te darás cuenta de que es mucho más fácil solucionarlo usando recursividad.